# how display the the contains of .txt file in VB.net and compare between them

Tags: vb.net, compare

i have four .txt files that contains an integer value and i want to display each one of these integers in a different box(4 boxes each one contains a value from the .txt file) inside VB.net. further more i want to compare between these results and execute one of these commands based on the highest value. `SerialPort1.Write("1/")
        SerialPort1.Write("2/")
        SerialPort1.Write("3/")
        SerialPort1.Write("4/")` thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to first get all of the text data from the *.txt files, this can easily be done by using [IO.File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Next you will want to ensure that the data received are valid Integers, this can easily be done by using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Finally you'll want to get the highest value, since they're all numeric values, simply use the [Enumerable.Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here is a quick example:

```
'Get all of the text from the desired file and assign it to the respective TextBox
TextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("file1.txt")
TextBox2.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("file2.txt")
TextBox3.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("file3.txt")
TextBox4.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("file4.txt")

'Check which TextBox has the highest value by first check if all are valid Integer values
Dim tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4 As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, tb1) AndAlso
   Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, tb2) AndAlso
   Integer.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, tb3) AndAlso
   Integer.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, tb4) Then

    'Get the highest value
    Dim highest As Integer = {tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4}.Max()

    'Do your command based on the highest value
    If ... Then

    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("One or more of the text files contain a value that cannot be converted into an Integer. Please check the files and try again.", "Invalid Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End If
```

Comment: System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\rN.txt") System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\rS.txt")
Dim tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4 As Integer
If Integer.TryParse("rN.Txt", tb1) AndAlso  Integer.TryParse("rS.Txt", tb4) Then  Dim highest As Integer = {tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4}.Max()
            If tb1 > tb4 Then
                result = matlab.Execute("cd C:\Users\Bo$$\Documents\MATLAB\")
                result = matlab.Execute("NORTH")  (but i ended up with: one or more of the text files contain a value that cannot be converted into a integer.please check the files )knowing my value was 2.4935633e+02  thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to store your data in a database such as mysql. And query the data you need.

However you can load your text into a string, then parse it into an integer

```
Dim lstValues as list(of Integer)
Dim file1 As String
Dim intGNum as integer
file1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt") 'copy same for other files

lstValue.add(integer.parse(file1))'duplicate for other files
'lstValue.add(integer.parse(file2)) 
'lstValue.add(integer.parse(file3))
'lstValue.add(integer.parse(file4))

intGNum=lstValue.Max();
```

Comment: Thanks but when i used it i got this error: 'lstValue' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: sorry add New before "list(of Integer)"

Comment: David's answer has the complete code you need with the addition of handling non-integers. My answer came with the assumption that all txt came with integers. however using multiple text files for single integers is slower than if you would have that information in a database table

Comment: the problem is that i really don't know how database works or how to implement my data in there.

Comment: Youtube-How to install local Dataase [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iP1wOSsKjW8)

Comment: Youtube - How to connect to database vb.net [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMLAXQR_YFI)

Comment: Thanks a lot MR. Ninjatalon.